# Sublime text Error after Windows update

Tags: windows-10, sublimetext3, stata

I am using [StataEditor](https://github.com/mattiasnordin/StataEditor) with Sublime Text 3 on a Windows 10 machine. After a windows update, Sublime gives the following error when I try to run my .do files. I suspect that this is happening because my "C:\Users\Mihir Sharma" path has a space in it. This wasn't a problem before the windows update. Would appreciate any leads on how to fix this!

```
cd "C:/Program Files (x86)/Stata15"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Stata15

. do c:\users\mihir sharma\appdata\local\temp\st_stata_temp.tmp
file c:\users\mihir.do not found
r(601);

. do c:\users\mihir sharma\appdata\local\temp\st_stata_temp.tmp
file c:\users\mihir.do not found
r(601);
```

Comment: What you're showing us are two Stata commands that will fail because you need `" "` around the filenames. On the face of it this has nothing to do with Windows or any external editor. It's just a Stata error in the code you're showing us.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of StataEditor for Sublime Text 3. I do not know what changed in the windows update, but I just released a new version (v0.8.2), where quotation marks are always included so that spaces should not be a problem. This should solve your problem.